# Inno components check error

Tags: inno-setup

i'm new to Inno setup, and Delphi. I wrote and install for an addon. I use a check condition for one of the components, but i get the following error message.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di22W.jpg)

```
[Components]
Name: "fmFiles"; Description: {cm:txtFmFiles}; Flags: fixed; Types: customInstall developerInstall defaultInstall minInstall; Check:dirNotExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\addon\FMC'))


[Code]
function dirNotExists(dir : String) : Boolean;
begin
    Result := not DirExists(dir);
end;
```

I understand the problem with this, but i don't know how to fix it. I want this component only checked if there is a folder not existing. And the user shouldn't be able to change anything on this.
But the user is able to change the path to the installation, so this check should be done AFTER he selected the correct install path.

I think i can use CurPageChanged function but how can i check/uncheck commponents from the code section?

==EDIT==

The actual problem is, that my addon requires another addon. if it's not installed i want to install it.

Comment: 1) The `Check` parameter does not un/check the component. It shows/hides it. 2) You cannot check/uncheck `fixed` component. - So what do you want. Describe your use case. This looks like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578).

Comment: well you are right. So i have an addon for a program and this addon requires another addon. I want to see whether this other addon is installed or not. If it isn't i want to install it, too. If it's already there, nothing to do

Comment: So do you need to display the other addon in "Components" list at all?

Comment: well i'd prefer to tell the user that this addon was missing and so it's installed. But if it's too complicate/not possible it doesn't need to be displayed in the components list

Comment: OK, and will there ever be a situation that the addon is actually installed before your application is installed? Or will it only ever be absent, if the application was never installed? + What do you want to show on updates? It does not make sense to me to to uncheck the component on update. Note that the uncheck indicates uninstall (while not really working in Inno Setup) rather than mene "not-update".

Comment: Yes there can be a situation where the other addon is already installed. No need for updates atm. And since the other addon is final (as far as i know) there won't be a reason to update this other addon if i update my addon

Comment: OK, but please make sure you understand the semantics of the "Components" section. It describes a final set of components, not components that are actually going to be installed/updated.